# How can i create a collection on statemint nft pallet without reserving 10 DOT

Tags: polkadot, nft, statemint

Is there some way i can use to create  a collection on statemint nft pallet without reserving 10 DOT i tried force create but it is currently disabled and i also tried utility batch all but it didn't worked there is one way i found but i don't understand how does it works https://statemine.statescan.io/#/extrinsics/323750-0 in this transaction 3 nft were create on statemine uniques pallet by polkadot decoded team if you understand this or you have an idea please share with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, the deposit is there for a reason.